# How to apply the ratio test to the following expression $a_{n+1} \le \frac{a_n - a_n^2}{2}$

Tags: calculus

It is known that $a_n$ is a positive sequence, I want to show by the ratio test that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$$
It is also known that:
$$a_{n+1} \le \frac{a_n - a_n^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence is positive, if $a_{n+1} \le \dfrac{a_n-a_n^2}{2}$ then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \dfrac{1-a_n}{2} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a_{n+1}\leq \frac{a_n-a_n^2}{2}\leq \frac{a_n}2$...